# Wrong Day From date

Tags: date

I get wrong Day from a Date.
I put in for example `formatter.date(from: "14.03.2019")` which is a Thursday and later in `formatter.weekSymbols` I get printed the day after it (Friday)

why is that happening? Here's my code
`

```
func returnFormattedDate() -> String {
    let formattedDay = String(format: "%02d.%02d", day, month)
    return "\(formattedDay).2019"
}

func returnWeekDay() -> String? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    print(returnFormattedDate())

    guard let todayDate = formatter.date(from: returnFormattedDate()) else { return nil }
    print(todayDate) // prints 2019-03-14 00:00:00 +0000

    let nameOfDay = formatter.weekdaySymbols[Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.weekday, from: todayDate)]
    print(nameOfDay) // prints 'Friday' instead of thursday
    return nameOfDay
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, de_DE, there is currently one hour ("in advance") difference from UTC, no? So when it's 2PM in Germany, it's 1PM in UTC, no? So "2019-03-13 23:00:00 +0000" which is in UTC, is "2019-03-14 00:00:00" in yours, no?

Comment: i guess so ? what then?

Comment: `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`.

Comment: okay now i get the right date: `2019-03-14 00:00:00 +0000` but why is the weekday still saying Friday instead of thursday?

Comment: Because you are not setting time zone of the calendar?

Comment: even after it i get the same day. `var calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calender.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!`

Comment: @SwiftNewling Because the first day is Sunday with value 1 but you are indexing at array with indices `0...6`.

Comment: and how can i change that? My First day of a week is monday not sunday

Comment: @SwiftNewling That's not about your local start of the week, it's about the calendar constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes in your code.

1. You have to set time zone
2. `weekday` values are 1...7 (1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday) but the array of `weekdaySymbols` obviously starts with index 0 (`weekdaySymbols[0] = Sunday`, `weekdaySymbols[6] = Saturday`). So let's just subtract `1`.

```
let dateString = "14.3.2019"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
// ERROR 1
// you have to set timezone. Since we don't care about time, let's just use UTC.
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let todayDate = formatter.date(from: dateString)!
print(todayDate)

var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

// ERROR 2: you are indexing incorrectly
let nameOfDay = formatter.weekdaySymbols[calendar.component(.weekday, from: todayDate) - 1]
print(nameOfDay)
```